# Is it possible to get Request Results from the Browser to my app

Tags: android, android-studio

That might be a stupid question but I'm really curious if this is possible or not.

Ok so we have an Android app with a textfield for username, another one for password and a simple Button. 
So is it possible that if i klick on the button, open a specific login site with also username and password textfields with the smartphones browser, fill those with the content of the username and password of the app and receive the Result in my App?

So basically I want to type the login data into the textfields in my app. Open the login site with the browser, fill the textfields automatically and get back to my app seeing if the username and password were legit.

Is something like this possible? Sorry if it is unclear what I want

Answer (score 0):

maybe deep linking can help you:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

with deep linking you can get params from url

edit:

see also:

https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android